# Search Roles in salesforce metadata

Tags: apex, metadata, eclipse, search, role-hierarchy

There are 3 roles which I want to know if it is referred in metadata or not.

But my question is using which keyword I need to search the roles ?

Currently I am using **Role** and **UserRole** keyword to search if it referred in the metadata and based on that I am searching particular role names.

Is there any easy method to search ?

Comment: That's the standard way I'm afraid. Setup -> Search - > Roles